# how to fit button size equally

Tags: android, android-layout

I have following layout which contains buttons:

[image]

I'm facing next problems:

1. First two buttons on the left side are not equal of the size to buttons on the right side of the layout.
2. Why did the buttons on the right side change background color? I want them to have default background color, like the one on the left, or how can I set them to different one, but also containing the image?
3. For first two buttons, how can I resize image, so that my text is set horizontally.

Below you can find my code:

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/defaultOptionsBackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5.0"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_white_48dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="499"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_white_48dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_place_white_48dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_place_white_48dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

On the following link you can find the icon:
https://design.google.com/icons/index.html#ic_place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. because the heights are set to wrap_content
2. because on two buttons you set background and the other two drawableStart. Change the `android:background` to change to something else. `drawableStart` will be shown before the text
3. add a `paddingEnd` with the same size of the drawable on the `start`.

Below the XML layout that I believe you want

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/defaultOptionsBackground"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="5.0"
                android:paddingEnd="48dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_white_48dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="499"
                android:paddingEnd="48dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_white_48dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingEnd="48dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_white_48dp"/>
            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingEnd="48dp"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_white_48dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Cool, that works. However, last question. For last two buttons, how can I center images in the center. It looks like there is not drawableCenter?

Comment: in center is the text. But if there's drawable on one side and not the other.. the text goes to the side. So if you have to use drawable in one side and not the other, you create a transparent drawable to fill the space. Alternatively you can play with the `gravity` parameter to position the text.

Comment: So in my case, I just want to have `        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_place_white_48dp"/>` and I have played around with gravity_layout and gravity with center parameter, but both of this did not set the image to the center :/

Comment: that's why I'm suggesting to create a transparent drawable to fill the other side.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try that

Comment: Figured out. I changed last two buttons to image buttons, and used src to set this image.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I re-read your question and my answer and my answer was pretty stupid. I edited it. Please check again. Transparent drawable was a stupid idea. You can just easily set `padding` on any side of the view. So if your drawableStart is 48dp, just add 48dp as paddingEnd.

Answer (score 0):

Most part of your question has been answered above by Budius. The answer to part of your 2nd question -  "how can I set buttons to have different color, but also contain the image?" -- You can set different color by using this line android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" in button layout.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello" />


</LinearLayout>
```